# Encode Json on a token by token basis in Python

Tags: python, json

I am wondering if there is any library that allows me to encode objects to json on a token by token basis, so that I do not have to hold a really huge object tree in memory.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use json.dump() (instead of `dumps()`) with a stream:

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
>>> json.dump(['streaming API'], io)
>>> io.getvalue()
'["streaming API"]'
```

Comment: This does not work, because I still have to put the whole ['streaming API'] structure in memory.  I want to generate a huge structure on the fly. At no moment is the whole structure held in memory, but I want to write the whole structure to a json strream piece by piece.

Comment: fair enough, but you don't have enough information in your question to tell us how you intend to have a python object that doesn't fit into memory, or how you intend to bring the object into memory piecemeal

Answer (score 0):

For an array object, it could be done this way. A dictionary would not be much different.

```
import json

# repos.json is from github,
# curl -i https://api.github.com/orgs/<organisation>/repos
# with some editing
repos = json.load(open("repos.json", "r"))
# for comparing the input vs. output
json.dump(repos, open("repos2.json", "w"),
          indent=2, check_circular=False, sort_keys=True)

with open("output.json", "w") as fp:
    first = True
    fp.write("[\n")

    # simulate what could be done if repo objects were read
    # one by one from somewhere
    for repo in repos:
        if not first:
            fp.write(",\n")
        else:
            first=False
        json.dump(repo, fp, indent=2, check_circular=False, sort_keys=True)
    fp.write("\n]\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to stream an object, you need a wrapper object that implements `__iter__()` and delegates:

def StreamingList(object):

```
def __init__(self, source):
    handle = source.open()

def __iter():
    return handle.__iter__() # the returned iterator must return one JSON-serializable object at a time
```

you can then do:

```
json.dumps(StreamingList(filename))
```

*this is a sketch*